# How to separate tokens in line using Unix?

Tags: file, unix, tokenize

How to separate tokens in line using Unix?

**[in]:**

```
some sentences are like this.
some sentences foo bar that
```

**[out:]**

```
some
sentences
are
like
this.

some
sentences
foo
bar
that
```

I could have done this in python as below, but **is there any unix way to achieve the same output?**

```
>>> import codecs
>>> outfile = codecs.open('outfile.txt','w','utf8')
>>> intext = "some sentences are like this.\n some sentences foo bar that"
>>> infile = codecs.open('infile.txt','w','utf8')
>>> print>>infile, intext
>>> for i in codecs.open('infile.txt','r','utf8'):
...     for j in i.split():
...             print>>outfile, j
...     print>>outfile
... 
>>> exit()

alvas@ubi:~$ cat outfile.txt 
some
sentences
are
like
this.

some
sentences
foo
bar
that
```

Comment: see also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779272/reverse-newline-tokenization-in-one-token-per-line-files-unix?noredirect=1#comment32949628_21779272

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
$ cat infile.txt
some sentences are like this.
some sentences foo bar that
$ sed 's/\s\+\|$/\n/g' infile.txt > outfile.txt
$ cat outfile.txt
some
sentences
are
like
this.

some
sentences
foo
bar
that
```

Comment: any idea how to do the reverse?

Comment: @alvas, Please post a separated question.

Answer (score 1):

Using xargs

```
xargs -n1 < file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's/ \|$/\n/g' < text
```

should do?