# Reverse newline tokenization in one-token per line files? - Unix

Tags: python, unix, sed, awk, xargs

[How to separate tokens in line using Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778582/how-to-separate-tokens-in-line-using-unix/21778655?noredirect=1#21778655) showed that a file is tokenizable using `sed` or `xargs`.

Is there a way to do the reverse?

**[in:]**

```
some
sentences
are
like
this.

some
sentences
foo
bar
that
```

**[out]:**

```
some sentences are like this.
some sentences foo bar that
```

The only delimiter per sentence is the `\n\n`. I could have done the following in python, but **is there a unix way?**

```
def per_section(it):
  """ Read a file and yield sections using empty line as delimiter """
  section = []
  for line in it:
    if line.strip('\n'):
      section.append(line)
    else:
      yield ''.join(section)
      section = []
  # yield any remaining lines as a section too
  if section:
    yield ''.join(section)

print ["".join(i).replace("\n"," ") for i in per_section(codecs.open('outfile.txt','r','utf8'))]
```

**[out:]**

```
[u'some sentences are like this. ', u'some sentences foo bar that ']
```

Comment: Is it always 5 words? What's the pattern to check when the new line should change, with the dot `.`?

Comment: no, it's not always 5 words, 5 words is a coincidence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using awk is eaiser to handle this kind of task:

```
awk -v RS="" '{$1=$1}7' file
```

if you want to keep multiple spaces in your each line, you could

```
awk -v RS="" -F'\n' '{$1=$1}7' file
```

with your example:

```
kent$  cat f
some
sentences
are
like
this.

some
sentences
foo
bar
that

kent$  awk -v RS=""  '{$1=$1}7' f   
some sentences are like this.
some sentences foo bar that
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `awk` command as follows:

```
awk -v RS="\n\n" '{gsub("\n"," ",$0);print $0}' file.txt
```

Set the record separator as `\n\n` which means the strings are tokenized in a group of lines separated by a blank line. Now, print that token after replacing all the `\n` by a space character.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n --posix 'H;$ {x;s/\n\([^[:cntrl:]]\{1,\}\)/\1 /gp;}' YourFile
```

Based on blank line separation so, each string could differ in length also